# Bulk change file extensions

Tags: 18.04, files, file-format, batch-rename

I have a folder with ~30 files. The are already BitTorrent metafiles that lack a .torrent suffix. I want to change all those files to .torrent files. How would I do that? In windows it was as easy as typing

```
ren *.* *.torrent
```

while being inside the folder with all those files.

I am not sure what the current file extension of those 30 files is.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Remember unlike Windows, Ubuntu does not always use file extensions to identify file type.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install rename:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Try:

```
rename 's/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/.torrent/' *.*
```

On another note, remember changing file extension won't change its file type or contents.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! I thought I would change the file type when I rename the files... 

Sorry I'm still really new to Linux and was used to that from Windows. 

What do I have to do to actually change the files to .torrent files? 

Thanks again!

Comment: What type of files are these that you are renaming as ".torrent"? Can you give more details into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *; do
  base=`echo "${file%.*}"`
  mv -- "${file}" "${base}.torrent"
done
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install krusader krename
```

Krusader has a menu for File-MultiRename on selected files in it's browser, which browser also can be filtered . krename can also be used in terminal and it's own gui when run without parameters.